# Error when running application - "|WARN|Fail to retrieve token com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint:"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been getting these errors for the past few days when I try run my app locally. I'm completely out of ideas of how to fix this. Any idea what could be the problem? Below is the trace. The app is using aws-sdk 11 and running on java 11.

```html
Jun21 20:44:14.245|INFO|Bean 'scheduledTaskExecutor' of type [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Jun21 20:44:14.247|WARN|Fail to retrieve token 
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint: 
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:100)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.getToken(InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.java:91)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.readResource(InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.java:69)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.readResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:66)
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getItems(EC2MetadataUtils.java:403)
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getData(EC2MetadataUtils.java:372)
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getData(EC2MetadataUtils.java:368)
    at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getEC2InstanceRegion(EC2MetadataUtils.java:283)
    at com.amazonaws.regions.Regions.getCurrentRegion(Regions.java:107)
    at com.genesys.outbound.threadpool.ThreadPoolExecutorAbortPolicy.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutorAbortPolicy.java:33)
    at com.inin.cont.config.RootConfig.getThreadPool(RootConfig.java:415)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:229)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:723)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at com.inin.cont.Server.main(Server.java:33)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Host is down (connect failed)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
```

Comment: To improve this question, please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - then edit your question. Show what you got, what you aim for, and what you get and make clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the SDK now logs a warning when it can't retrieve the [AWS instance metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html). It may help to specify which AWS region you want using an [environment variable](https://githubmemory.com/repo/jnshubham/aws-glue-local-etl-docker/issues/3) (I haven't seen this work, but others have):

```
export AWS_REGION=us-east-1
```

Alternately, the Spring Cloud team recommends suppressing the warning:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/556

https://github.com/juho9000/spring-cloud-aws/commit/24edbdc57086f1043d3a49f6c8841cc1751ee747

> On application startup, for its internal purposes Spring Cloud AWS performs a check if application runs in AWS cloud environment
> by using `EC2MetadataUtils` class provided by AWS SDK. Starting from version 1.11.678, AWS SDK logs a warning message with exception when this check is made outside of AWS environment.
> This warning message can be hidden by setting `ERROR` logging level on `com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils` class.
>
> logging.level.com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils=error